# I have a pivot table range copied and pasted in a cell I want to reference that cell for the pivot table to update info

Tags: excel

I have a table range in a cell

I want to set up the pivot tables so when I update that single cell it updates all the pivot tables together

is there a non vba means to accomplish this?

Comment: What solutions have you already tried?

Comment: Hi Chris, I have tried to put the table range in a dedicated cell but and tried to change the data source by pointing to the cell but it does not work

Comment: Would it be an option for you to define a name for the data range, and when you need to  use different data then change the reference of the name?